# Javascript: How to get month from week number and year?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get month from given week number and year. Can someone help?

Example:
Week - 48
Year  - 2023
Output -  11

Comment: When do you consider the week numbers to start in a year?

Comment: Determine the first week of a year (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#The_ISO_week_date_system) and find out the date of Monday in that week. Add  `7 * (weekNumber - 1)` days to this date.

Answer (score 1):

This will extrapolate the month by getting the total milliseconds from the number of weeks.

```js
//Example: Week - 48 Year - 2023 Output - 11
let weeknumber = 48
let month = new Date(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * weeknumber).getMonth()

console.log(month)
```

Comment: no, there are leap year, so you have to take in account also the year

Comment: 1 day extra in a year won't affect the month number

Comment: It will if the date range is quite large. Also, not every year starts on week 1....

Comment: @SureshMangs yes, since you are taking the month from the first day of that week... maybe the first day is 29 Feb XXXX

Comment: also, we should take in account that not all years starts with the same day... then we have to define a week, if it starts from Monday or Sunday... it's a very strange question and we have very few informations

Comment: @0stone0 on top of that, years may start on a different date *based on the country*. Some countries consider the 1st of January to be the first week even if it's, say, a Wednesday, others consider that to be part of the last week of last year and week 1 starts on the first Monday of the new year. [The ISO week counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) considers the first week to be the one where the *the Thursday falls in January for the first time*.